# Modx. Apache URL Rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, modx

I faced with URL rewrite issue. Please help me to understand where is the problem or show me the way where to look.

Before the issue appeared I moved my modx evo to another host. There I faced with compatiblity issue. I used modx 1.0.6. On server installed php 5.5 (I can't find information about compatibility modx and php5.5. Everything except url rewrite is working well). I upgraded modx to 1.0.15

So to reproduce the issue you need to enable frendly urls and open any page. You get following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /gallery was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at zvezda-vostoka.ru Port 80
```

Here is htaccess:

```
php_flag register_globals Off
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value date.timezone Europe/Moscow

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.zvezda-vostoka\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.zvezda-vostoka.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The same issue, as posted below: 404 The requested URL was not found

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Thank you for proper direction. I put 'Deny from all'. Saw that nothing happen. Then saw **AllowOverride None** in apache config for <Directory /var/www/>. And changed it to **AllowOverride All**

Comment: @zhartaunik If that solved your issue, please post that as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put **Deny from all** at the beginning of .htaccess.

Saw that nothing happen.

Then saw **AllowOverride None** in apache config for `<Directory /var/www/>`.

And changed it to **AllowOverride All**